# Delete an array which is inside another array using java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey can anyone help me by telling how to delete the data an array which is inside another array.

eg: alpha[] is an array which has two arrays inside it of length [1-100] and [101-200] now i need to delete only the first array from alpha[].

Comment: Like `alpha[0]=null` ? But what do you mean with `length [1-100]` ? Maybe you should show more code so that the context is clearer.

Comment: thanks for message. I can add screenshot so I can explain better. But I am not able to do it. I need to have 10 reputation to add images. Getting crazy...

Comment: A screenshot ? You probably need to add 5 lines of code instead.

Comment: No my friend. Code is very very distributed. The value to array is a return value of method. And that method is linked to many other methods. I debugged using net beans and took a snap of the array at that instance. Wanna an post to explain better.

Comment: We don't want to see the real code, we want to see the minimal code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are fixed in size, you cannot resize them after creating them. You can remove an existing item by setting it to null:

```
alpha[0]=null
```

Comment: I am aware of that. my situation is this, I declared a array as below
   static byte[] headerPacket;

then two arrays are added to it dynamically. I wanna delete one array which is added in first place. I am not able to attach the screenshot, or I can explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `Arrays` utility class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

If you are interested in just getting a sub array out of an array a good way to do that is `Arrays.copyOfRange(alpha, 101, 200)`.

If you have a two dimensional array and you are only interested in one of the "rows" you can do `Arrays.copyOf(alpha[1], alpha[1].length)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of these approaches:

```
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] subArray = new int[2];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, subArray, 0, 2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray));
    => output: 1,2

    subArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, 2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray));
    => output: 1,2
```